# How do I check my gedit version?

Tags: gedit

I want to install some plugins for gedit, and I need to know my gedit version to install the correct plugins.
How do I check it?

Note: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: here is a list: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-plugins-to-extend-and-make-gedit-a-more-useful-text-editor-linux/

Comment: @mon I recommend posting a separate question about how to get formatting and syntax checking in Gedit, with a specific description of what you need.

Comment: most Linux apps give you the version by `--version`, `-v` or `-V`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Alternative to the desktop version: command line it would be...

```
$ gedit --version
gedit - Version 3.22.1
```

Comment: Short version: `gedit -V`

Comment: yeah and then someone asks: what is "-V"? :P

Answer (score 21):

For version it's Help > About and you should get this:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can use `apt` to get any package's version:

```
$ apt list --installed gedit
gedit/stable 3.22.0-1
```

or `dpkg`:

```
$ dpkg -l gedit
||/ Name              Version        ...
+++-==========================================
ii  gedit             3.22.0-1       ...
```

For more info about the version number:

```
man deb-version
```

Comment: Note: That list's the *package* version, which isn't necessarily the same thing as the product version. It often is the same thing, or the two are very closely related to each other; but they can easily be different.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yeah, that's right ... I updated the answer with a reference to related man page.

Answer (score 5):

Another method is to check the "Installed:" clause of

```
$ apt-cache policy gedit
```